# PHP code simply isn't recognised by browser

Tags: php, mysql, browser, mysqli, xampp

I've been working on a small web project where I am belatedly attempting to use some PHP code (please note I am a beginner to the language). The basis of the (slightly farcical) site is that users submit jokes and can then vote on them based on their quality. So far I've just attempted to write the basic HTML structure of the page and the only PHP in the file is simply trying to connect to a phpmyadmin database on localhost. I'm using XAMPP to test my code. The Apache and MySQL modules are running when I try to load the file in Chrome. The file is saved as a .php. The file's text is below:

```
<div class="fields">
        <p>
            Type in your joke in the field below.
        </p>
        <form>
            Joke: 
            <br>
            <textarea type="text" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>
<?php
$DBServer = 'localhost'; // e.g 'localhost' or '192.168.1.100'
$DBUser   = 'samuel';
$DBPass   = 'samuel';
$DBName   = 'jokes';

$conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);

// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

?>
    </div>
```

The PHP code is pretty much taken from a tutorial on using mysqli, so the comments aren't mine. I made the "samuel" user earlier. In Chrome instead of anything meaningful coming up only this writing came up was displayed :

```
connect_error) { trigger_error('Database connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error,    E_USER_ERROR); } ?>
```

Which is just part of the writing from the PHP code. To see if this was just a problem with my syntax I made another .php file containing the simplest code possible:

```
<body>
<?php
echo "Hello world!";
?>
</body>
```

When I opened the file in Chrome nothing at all was displayed. I'm really hoping this is all just a product of a gaping error that can be easily remedied. Thanks for taking the time to read!

Comment: What is the address your are opening, does it start with `file://` or `http://`? Also, do you see the complete file including the php tags when you view the source?

Comment: What url do you use for each file? Did you set up apache on your machine?

Comment: check if `mod_php` is activated in apache config

Comment: PHP runs on the *server*, not in the client. Whatever you're using to serve the page is not running the PHP, it's just delivering the raw source to the client. You need to properly configure your server.

Comment: Ok, so how can I configure the Apache server on XAMPP and after that where should PHP code be written? In the page source or somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, turns out that I just had to move the files to the htdocs folder in xampp and the correct PHP error message comes up! Only problem is the PHP won't be read if I put the files in a subfolder within htdocs, which would make it much neater. Any solutions?